# Plot algorithm excution time in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, figure, timeit

I am trying to compare the execution time of two algorithms.
till now, I've appended the start and end execution time in a list as follows:-

```py
myList = [['algorithm_1', start time, end time], ['algorithm_2', start time, end time]]
```

**Example**

```
myList = [['algorithm_1', 1647030884.8106081, 1647030884.811373], ['algorithm_2', 647030884.8262258, 1647030890.0927901]]
```

The time measured in seconds

**My question:** could you please advise how to plot the difference between the start time and end time (algorithm execution time) of both algorithms in the same figure?

here is my code:

```py
def get_algorithm_execution_time(algorithm_name):
    time_list = timeit.repeat(stmt=algorithm_name,
                              setup='',
                              timer=time.perf_counter,
                              number=1, globals=globals())
    execution_time = min(time_list)
    return execution_time

start_time = time.time()
execution_time = get_algorithm_execution_time('algorithm_1')
end_time = start_time + execution_time
algorithms_execution_time.append(['algorithm_1', start_time, end_time])

start_time = time.time()
best_time = get_algorithm_execution_time('algorithm_2')
end_time = start_time + execution_time
algorithms_execution_time.append(['algorithm_2', start_time, end_time])

start = []
end = []
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 6))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in algorithms_execution_time:
    start.append(i[1])
    end.append(i[2])
plt.plot(start[0], end[0], "b")
plt.plot(start[1], end[1], "r")
plt.show()
```

Currently, the figure doesn't show anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the next code snippet:

```py
def graph_series(list_of_execution_time):
    from matplotlib import pyplot


    values = {}
    for element in list_of_execution_time:
        if element[0] not in values:
            values[element[0]] = [(element[2] - element[1])]
        else:
            values[element[0]].append(element[2] - element[1])
    for key, value in values.items():
        pyplot.plot(value, markersize=20,label=key)
    pyplot.legend()
    pyplot.show()
```

It takes a list of lists, iterates, creates a list of values for each algorithm, and plots it by matplotlib [here is manual](https://howtothink.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PvL_H.html).

Use pip to install it:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

You can check it by next code:

> You have to send more than 2 points to each algorithm to see the graph.

```py
myList = [['algorithm_1', 1, 2], ['algorithm_1', 1, 5], 
            ['algorithm_2', 1, 3], ['algorithm_2', 1, 6], ]

graph_series(myList)
```

**Here is the result:**

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWBYp.png)